# webservice annotation for soapui

Tags: java, soapui

How do I set up an annotation for attributes in a SOAP request?
My example:

```
public class Example {
    @WebMethod()
    public void test(@WebParam(name="pingRequest")PingRequest HotelPingRQ) {}
}

public class PingRequest
{
    private String echo;

    public String getEcho() {
        return echo;
    }

    public void setEcho(String echo) {
        this.echo = echo;
    }
}
```

If I generate a WSDL and put it into SoapUI I get this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:door="http://www.test.com/doorway">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <door:test>
      <pingRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
          <echo>?</echo>
       </pingRequest>
   </door:test>
</soapenv:Body>
```

but I want something more like the following, with `echo` as an attribute and no test element:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:door="http://www.test.com/doorway">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <pingRequest echo="?" />
</soapenv:Body>
```

How can I convert the `echo` parameter to an attribute on `pingRequest` instead of a nested element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)    
public class PingRequest
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String echo;

    public String getEcho() {
        return echo;
    }

    public void setEcho(String echo) {
        this.echo = echo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another,how i can set up like following?  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:door="http://www.test.com/doorway">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <door:PingRequest echo="?" />
</soapenv:Body>

Comment: Try an @XmlRootElement(namespace="test.com/doorway") annotation in your class PingRequest. But I don't really know if this will help. You should open a new question next time, it gives your problem more attention by the other users.

Comment: DirkNM,thanks,but it didn't work,i open another question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080760/webservice-annotation-issues-with-soapui