# webservice annotation issues with soapui

Tags: java, soapui

My manager gave me a wsdl url to me today,and he want to publish a same wsdl on our side,i met an issue while combine the annotation request with spring,can someone help ?The custom request following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:door="http://www.derbysoft.com/doorway">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <door:PingRequest Token="?" UserName="?" Password="?" Echo="?"/>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

what i can generated like following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:door="http://www.test.com/doorway">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <door:PingRequest>
     <PingRequest Echo="?" Token="?" UserName="?" Password="?"/>
  </door:PingRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It always contain more element with method name,how i can remove that ?I attached my source here.

```
@WebService(name="Example", targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/doorway", serviceName="Example")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Example {
@WebMethod(operationName="toSayHello",action="sayHello",exclude=false)
public String sayHello(@WebParam(name="userName")String userName) {
    return "Hello:" + userName;
}

@WebMethod()
public void PingRequest(@WebParam(name="PingRequest")PingRequest pingRequest) {
}
```

}

Entity:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class PingRequest
{
@XmlAttribute(name="Echo")
private String echo;
@XmlAttribute(name="Token")
private String token;
@XmlAttribute(name="UserName")
private String userName;
@XmlAttribute(name="Password")
private String password;

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEcho() {
    return echo;
}

public void setEcho(String echo) {
    this.echo = echo;
}
```

}

Many thanks in advance !!

Kind Regards,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the way to do this,us wsimport tool to do this,this will generate all the entity class and webservice annotation info,also the annotation for this case should like  this:@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)